# How can I do this sort of table in HTML?

Tags: html, html-table

```
__________________________________________
|________________________________________| << cell uses 100% of the row space
|____________________|___________________| << each cell there use 50% of the row
```

How can I do this with HTML?

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/m2mbs/

use this for rows

```
rowspan="x"
```

and this for columns

```
colspan="x"
```

with x being the desired span of the cells.

Comment: first answer & best answer

Comment: Both yours and Marcel Gwerder's answer are good, I'll let people vote for best one :) thanks

Comment: The only thing that is missing in this answer is the width 50% which makes sure that the bottom two cells are always the same size.

Answer (score 2):

Use `colspan` to span the single column over the two:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">100%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="half">50%</td>
        <td class="half">50%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And set the width with css:

```
.half {
    width: 50%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CbCxd/)

Comment: Both yours and Sieu Phan's answer are good, I'll let people vote for best one :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

1-Download the sorttable.js

2-Include the sorttable.js, by putting a link to it in the HEAD of your page, like so:

3-Mark your table as a sortable one by giving it a class of "sortable":

```
 <table class="sortable">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it is done. (border=1 has been added to enhance clarity of the output)

```
<table border=1>
 <tr>
  <td colspan='2'>row1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>row2</td><td>row2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```